# How do i stop chartkick from showing the X-axis date (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

first time at stackoverflow.

it shows a date of every point in the graph under the x-axis.
can someone help me removing it?

```
 <%= area_chart website.pings.limit(5).order(created_at: :desc).pluck(:created_at, (:ms)),
 width: "70x", height: "130px", messages: {empty: "No Ping made yet"}, curve: false, refresh: 10 %>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8zQS.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout this issue as wel. As it implies with your issue.
[How to hide axis using Chartkick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974479/how-to-hide-axis-using-chartkick-js)

And Chartkick also has options that you can chance if you follow the documentation: [Chartkick website](https://chartkick.com/)

So when combining the answers you would have to add this to your code:

```
<%= area_chart website.pings.limit(5).order(created_at: :desc).pluck(:created_at, (:ms)),
 width: "70x", height: "130px", messages: {empty: "No Ping made yet"}, 
curve: false, refresh: 10, library: { scales: { xAxes: [{ display: false }] } } %>
```

With `library: { scales: { xAxes: [{ display: false }] } }` you can add options, and the scales are the x and y scales where you can change the options of too.

Checkout the full API here: [Full Chartkick API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html)

Comment: thenk u nlxdodge