# How to hide axis in column_chart using chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

In chartkick's column_chart, I want to remove the axes of the chart as shown in the attached image.

I tried this code, but I couldn't hide axis.

```
<%= column_chart data, library: { hAxis: { textPosition: 'none'  },vAxis: { textPosition: 'none'  } } %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsKC.png)

Comment: I think you have to pass options directly to the charting library with `library` option

Comment: I understand.thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide axis using Chartkick.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974479/how-to-hide-axis-using-chartkick-js)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know how to do it in ruby-on-rails.It was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is now solved.

```
<%= column_chart data, library: { scales: { xAxes: [display: false], yAxes: [display: false] } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe depends on the underlying library, but when using chartjs this is what worked

````
 <%= column_chart data, library: { scales: {
                         x: {
                           ticks: {
                             display: false
                           }
                         },
                         y: {
                           ticks: {
                             display: false
                           }
                         }
                       } } %>
    ```
````